# hadoop run example Input path does not exist

Tags: hadoop

when I run
 `./bin/hadoop jar ./share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-*.jar grep /user/hadoop/input /user/hadoop/output 'dfs[a-z.]+'`
 on master/slave.

something wrong,`Input path does not exist: hdfs://master:9000/user/root/grep-temp-1940166004`

but my input path is `/user/hadoop/input`,and run `./bin/hdfs dfs -ls /user/hadoop/input` shows that `Found 9 items`,it's OK. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpfmj.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create **`/user/root/`** on HDFS.

It doesn't matter if `/user/hadoop/` exists unless you actually run the command as the `hadoop` user account (not root)

Answer (score 0):

When any `hadoop` command is run, it takes `hdfs` user as a current logged-in user on Linux.

It seems you are running this command as `root` user which doesn't exist in hdfs(No hdfs user as `root`).

Either you mention fully qualified path as an input or run the `hadoop` command as `hdfs` user or the user(Linux as well hdfs) where your input file exists.